# How can I profile SQL Azure?

Tags: monitoring, profiler, azure-sql-database

I am writing a web site that uses SQL Azure heavily. However, it is painfully slow.

Is there an easy way to profile the live SQL Azure instance?

Comment: You will want to follow this link for information on how to monitor performance of SQL Azure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394114.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929586/sql-azure-profiling/49217396#49217396

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used the [MVC Mini Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) as part of an application to profile SQL Azure but depending on your application it may or may not work. What kind of tasks are you doing that need profiling?

Answer (score 3):

It won't help you trace existing calls from your website but you can still obtain interesting performance metrics by running SQL commands from this tool directly: [Enzo SQL Baseline](http://enzosqlbaseline.codeplex.com/). It offers options to load commands in parallel to simulate load and helps you compare performance metrics over multiple runs.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a "light version" available, where you can analyze your queries and see resource consumption.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benko/cloudtip-14-how-do-i-get-sql-profiler-info-from-sql-azure)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you can also use the [CSS SQL Azure Diagnostics tool](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2011/05/09/sql-azure-diagnostics-tool-available/)* from Microsoft support to run some queries on the server that show you missing indexes and popular queries.

<sup>*</sup> It appears this tool is no longer available (11 January 2015)

Comment: The tool can't no longer be found.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Cotega Monitoring service](http://www.cotega.com).  It has the ability to monitor and notify you of issues and also the ability to perform [deep database analysis](https://cotega.com/docs/analyze_database) on your database to help diagnose issues such as why your database is running so painfully slow.

Disclaimer: I work on this service.

Answer (score 0):

The most close to SQL profiler, that I found to be able work with azure sql, is [sql-workload-profiler](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507002820/https://cbailiss.wordpress.com/sql-workload-profiler/)
However note, that it’s a beta version of a tool, created by a single person, and it is not too convinient to use

Answer (score -2):

You can't run Profiler against SQL Azure.

Comment: He's asking about a way to profile a SQL Azure instance. It doesn't necessarily have to be with [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).